# APEX 'waiting for data' chart label not visible

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, anychart

while loading data for a chart in APEX 5 (default html5) the user is presented with a 'Waiting for data...' label at the chart position. Unfortunately this label is only visible when the chart has a fixed 'width'.

Is there a workaround so that the label is always visible? Working with a fixed width is no option due to window resizing and different screen resolutions.

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Comment: in apex 4.2.1 i leave field "width" empty (though field is required), but i set only height (300px), and when i resize window all work good, and displayed "Loading in %", try same and answer me pls

Comment: Setting just the hight is at least in APEX 5 not working. :-( (But thanks for the idea.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I came up with is calling

`$(window).trigger("apexwindowresized");`

after the page load.

This is not pretty but it works.